# No puedo hacer un Redirect hacia una url externa

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Estoy creando un filtro de accion para validar ciertos datos en los cuales si se cumplen sigue el flujo normal de la aplicacion, pero en caso contrario debe ser redireccionado hacia una url externa.

Hasta el momento eh estado haciendo pruebas y nada me ah funcionado para redireccionar hacia una url externa, el codigo actual que poseo es este:

```
public class ValidateActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isBloqueado = true;
        if (isBloqueado)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("www.google.cl", true);
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar para ver que estoy haciendo mal? ya que cuando pasa por el `redirect` me devuelve un error `404` por que queda así la url

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira esto: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect/

Comment: Prueba con `http://` al principio de la url.

Comment: Gracias a los dos, ahora tengo otro problema... creare una nueva pregunta para ello. Haber si me pueden ayudar igual.

Comment: Acá esta el link del otro error https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175889/error-system-web-httpexception-al-hacer-un-response-redirect

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que especificar la Url completa, ya que no se encuentra en tu aplicación.

```
if (isBloqueado)
{
   return Redirect("http://www.google.cl");
}
```

Comment: easy my friend.