# Error System.Web.HttpException al hacer un Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un filtro de acción que me valida si es que existe un dato o este es `true` o `false` para luego hacer un redirect hacia una url externa. Funciona bien el redireccionamiento. Pero el filtro lo tengo en mi controlador en forma global y al ingresar al `controller` por `GET` me lanza una excepción por el `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` que esta en una vista parcial a la cual llamo en mi pagina que estoy ingresando por GET.

Mi clase de filtro:

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isBloqueado = true;
        if (isBloqueado)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://www.detacoop.cl", true);
            filterContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Mi Form que esta en una vista parcial, ejemplo: `_Footer` la cual es dependencia de mi vista que quiero renderizar, por ejemplo: MiVistaController

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat u-mar-RL-1 right">Cerrar sesión</a>
    }
```

Y me lanza la excepción acá `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

> System.Web.HttpException: 'El servidor no puede anexar un encabezado después de enviar los encabezados HTTP.'

Quien me puede ayudar a ver por que sucede esto?

Answer (score 1):

Quizá ya lo resolviste, o le pueda servir a alguien más.

Creo que el error está en el `Response.Redirect` ya que deberías pasar el `EndResponse` en `false` para no llamar a este método que detiene la ejecución de la página y genera el evento `EndRequest`.

Quedaría así:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://www.detacoop.cl", false);
```

En este enlace tenés más información: [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpResponse_Redirect_System_String_System_Boolean_)
Y la respuesta a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707465/when-should-i-use-response-redirecturl-true) quizá te lo aclare mejor.